# Pass an object to a class and call it in an static function in the same class

Tags: c++, static

I am using gdal to do some raster works, well it has a GDALWarpAppOptionsSetProgress function which gets an static function to show its progcess. here you can find its link :[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180705053317/http://www.gdal.org:80/gdal__utils_8h.html#a6ed3c9681cabcfcbd6fc87d427762482)
and this link

http://gdal.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.6.0/gdal_8h_5703b651695c0cbe6f3644a0a18dda8b.html

well I know I must write an static function to use it, here is my function

```
static int My_FN_GDALTermProgress( double dfComplete, const char *pszMessage, void *pData)
{

    if(progressBar){
        progressBar->setValue(FN_GDAL_PROGRESS_VALUE);
    }
  double FN_GDAL_PROGRESS_VALUE = dfComplete * 100;
   return TRUE;
}
```

well i have a class named `gdal_dem` which is like this

```
#include "gdal_dem.h"
#include "gdal_wrap.h"
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "cpl_string.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "ogr_spatialref.h"
#include "gdal_utils_priv.h"
#include "cpl_error.h"
#include <QString>
#include "commonutils.h"
#include <QFile>
gdal_dem::gdal_dem(QString SrcFilename):
    SrcFile(SrcFilename)
{


}


float FN_GDAL_PROGRESS_VALUE = 0.0f;

static int  My_FN_GDALTermProgress(double dfComplete,
                                  CPL_UNUSED const char * pszMessage,
                                  CPL_UNUSED void * pProgressArg )
{
    FN_GDAL_PROGRESS_VALUE = dfComplete * 100;
    printf("Progress: %f\n",FN_GDAL_PROGRESS_VALUE);
    return true;
}

////


int gdal_dem::colorrelief(QString Dstanationfile,QString colorfile){

    

   .....
        if(!(psOptionsForBinary->bQuiet))
{
    prgFunc=My_FN_GDALTermProgress;
    GDALDEMProcessingOptionsSetProgress(psOptions, prgFunc,NULL);
}


    ......
}
```

In above code I can set the above mentioned function in processing  option and it works fine. but my problem is when I want to update a progress bar. I have a `QProgressBar` and it is in my main class. How can I pass it into the static function? I tried these ways:
1- I tried to get progressbar in my gdal_dem and also defined a static variable in `gdal_dem` and tried to set its value and update it in `My_FN_GDALTermProgress`, the problem is because `progressbar`  is also static I can see it in wrap.cpp's contractor,
2-I tried to define a new `My_FN_GDALTermProgress` function in my main apps class but it must be static and I faced this error `cannot declare member function to have static linkage`

3- I also tried this method but it does not work
https://www.badprog.com/c-errors-warnings-cannot-declare-member-function-static-void-myclassmymethod-to-have-static-linkage

Well, How can I pass a parameter to my gdal_dem class and update its value in an static class in it?

Comment: wrap.cpp is a file, not a class. You don’t show a class.

Comment: @manni66 thanks I edited my question, my class name is gdal_dem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pData` argument. You can pass anything you want to it when registering the static function. In this case, you can pass a pointer to your `QProgressBar` object:

```
QProgressBar* qProgBarObj = // ...
GDALDEMProcessingOptionsSetProgress(psOptions, prgFunc, qProgBarObj);
```

The static function will then receive it as the third argument:

```
static int My_FN_GDALTermProgress(double dfComplete, const char *pszMessage, void *pData)
{
    auto progBar = reinterpret_cast<QProgressBar*>(pData);
    progBar->setValue(/* ... */);
    // ...
}
```